# What are the consequences of creating a branch from a subfolder of trunk in SVN?

Tags: svn, branch

I thought that normally when you branch, you branch the whole trunk, but in my company I've seen people branch subfolders of trunk and deeper- are there any practical consequences of this besides confusion when you try to find the right directory in the trunk to merge back into?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not the branching.. it is the merging:

**Never** merge back into such a "subtree" folder. Why? Subversion will store its merge-info into this subtree folder. And as soon as this happens, nobody can use merge -reintegrate anymore.

[Look here for more information](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.finalword):

> Avoid subtree merges and subtree mergeinfo, perform merges only on the
>   root of your branches, not on subdirectories or files

This means as long as you have subtree merge-infos hanging around in your trunk you can not use the -reintegrate option, which you usually should use, because in this way merging is much much easier.

Comment: It seems not same thing. The doc said about only merge paritial in branch(create on the root), the problem is asking merge whole branch(create on the subfolder)

Comment: hmm, I cannot understand what you are trying to state here.. Can you rephrase your thought?  Especially what do you mean by "the problem is asking merge whole branch(create on the subfolder)"?

Comment: Project root folder is A, A has sub folder B, C. People can create a branch on folder B. This branch only contain partial data of whole project. In classical usage, people always create branch on root folder A, however you can create branch on subfolder aslo. The refered doc should talking about not merge only subfolder B of a branch which created on root folder A. Simply say: the doc says: create a branch on root folder A, NOT only merge B in this branch to trunk. This question says: create a branch on sub folder B, merge B to trunk.

Answer (score 3):

exactly what you said. SVN is flexible enough that you can branch from anywhere in the tree, which is impressive, until you want to merge it back and then you have difficulty managing the mess you've created. Now it makes sense sometimes (eg you have a top level directory with other stuff in there, or you need a very special localised branch to fix a specific screwup) but in general you want to keep things simple for yourself.

That means choosing a root to use as your branch, and sticking with it, even if this means branching from the top level only. Things become much simpler to manage then. The cost of branching is negligible even if you do this.